# Add quotation marks to a text file

Tags: bash, sed

I need to add quotation marks to a list. I'm going to import this list to mailman later.

What I've is a list like this:

```
SurName Name email@host.foo
otherSurName otherName otheremail@host.bar
```

What I need is:

```
"SurName Name" email@host.foo
```

I expect this to be possible using sed, but can't imagine how.

Comment: Is you entire file ordered like this?

Comment: yes, just some of the lines are missing name & surname...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
sed -r 's/^(.*) +(.*@.*)/"\1" \2/' file
```

or

```
sed -r 's/^(.*) +([^ ]+)$/"\1" \2/' file
```

### Note

this form allow to have `0 to N` spaces in the names part, the `sed` command will take care about that

Comment: Both just give a list of 'email@host.foo' entry's, they seem to totally cut of the name's... :-(

Comment: shame on me! during my first test's I used the old version of the list which only contained the mail addi's... SORRY With the correct "file" your first line worked as expected!!!

Answer (score 1):

If your entire file is ordered like this, you can simply use
        `sed -e 's/^\(.*\) \(.*\) \(.*\)$/"\1 \2" \3/'`

Answer (score 1):

The first quote is easy, `s/^/"/`, the second one is a bit trickier, but you can anchor it to the e-mail address with this pattern: `s/ *[^@ ]*@[^@]*$/"&/`, e.g.:

```
sed 's/^/"/; s/ *[^@ ]*@[^@]*$/"&/' file
```

Output:

```
"SurName Name" email@host.foo
"otherSurName otherName" otheremail@host.bar
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another sed option:

```
sed '{
s/^/"/
s/ \([^ ]*\)$/" \1/
}' inputFile
```

same thing on a single line:

```
sed 's/^/"/;s/ \([^ ]*\)$/" \1/' inputFile
```

Answer (score 1):

With `awk` you could do it like this:

```
awk '{$1="\""$1; $2=$2"\""}1' file
```

Test

```
$ awk '{$1="\""$1; $2=$2"\""}1' file
"SurName Name" email@host.foo
"otherSurName otherName" otheremail@host.bar
```

If you also want to handle the case of only two columns do this:

```
$ awk '{if (NF==2) $1="\""$1"\""; else {$1="\""$1; $2=$2"\""}}1' file
"SurName Name" email@host.foo
"otherSurName otherName" otheremail@host.bar
"thirdname" sdfff@sdff.go
```

Or if know there are only 2 or 3 columns you can do it a bit shorter:

```
awk '{$1="\""$1;$(NF-1)=$(NF-1)"\""}1' file
```

If you want to handle lines with no names do this:

```
awk '{if(NF>2){$1="\""$1; $2=$2"\""}}1' file
```

demo

```
$ awk '{if(NF>2){$1="\""$1; $2=$2"\""}}1' file
"SurName Name" email@host.foo
"otherSurName otherName" otheremail@host.bar
thirdname sdfff@sdff.go
sdfdf@sddf.su
```

Comment: They both wrap mail addi's in quotation Mark's in line's not containing a name...

Comment: @Mircsicz I added one that only adds quotes only if there are more than 2 words in the line